# eigenvectors of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2  \\
        2 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

I have found the the eigenevalues $\lambda_1$ = $4$ and $\lambda_2$ = $0$

the problem is that when I try to find the eigenvectors I only get 0 vectors and they're supposed to be non-zeros vectors

Comment: Can you show your work on calculating the eigenvalues? There seems to be a mistake.

Comment: These are not the eigenvalues, that's why.

Comment: EIgenvalues are $3$ and $-1$.

Comment: What is $A\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\\pm1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: $A-\lambda_2I=A$ isn't singular, so $\lambda_2$ can't be an Eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are wrong. They are $3$ and $-1$:the solutions of $0=p_A(x)=\det(A-xI)=(1-x)^2-4=x^2-2x-3$

The eigenvectors for $3$ are the vectors in:

$$\ker(A-3I)=\ker \begin{pmatrix} -2 &2 \\ 2 & -2 \end{pmatrix}=\left<\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1 \end{pmatrix}\right>.$$

and equally for $-1$:

$$\ker(A+I)=\ker \begin{pmatrix} 2 &2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\left<\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1 \end{pmatrix}\right>.$$